# How can I add geotagging information to aerial photos?

Tags: geotagging, gopro, aerial-photography

I have a small high wing airplane.  I want to take aerial photographs and use them in DeLorme Xmap 8 software program.  I have a GoPro camera 3, which I can mount to a wing strut and take pictures through the camera's wifi via an app on my iPad.  I don't know if these pictures will be GPS referenced. In other words, will the pictures show up on the map where they are supposed to be?

Comment: Hello new person.  It would help us if you can expand your question to tell us if you've tried your setup on the ground and what your results were and where your stuck.  Do you know how to check the exif data for geotag information for example.

Comment: @JamesSnell GPS doesn't depend on altitude, so if it doesn't work in the air it won't work on the ground either (that's true GPS, not the stuff they call GPS in cellphones, which is really triangulating reception towers).

Comment: @jwenting - I hadn't expected people might interpret my request for clarification in that way...  but I can see how you got there.  Just to confirm the check on the ground is to see if exif geotags were being generated (and according to the answer the GoPro app does not do it.)

Comment: DO NOT USE GOPRO WIFI ON YOUR AIRCRAFT! It interferes with the RC system, and without a suitable auto-pilot you WILL lose the aircraft. No, the GoPro does not have a GPS sensor.

Comment: @Jasmine I understood *small high wing airplane* to mean something like a Cessna, not a model.

Comment: @Jasmine the OP's profile reads "I recently got my pilot's license and am looking forward to taking pictures from above!" - I suspect this isn't referring to a drone or other unmanned aircraft in this case.

Comment: Yes very good, I don't check profiles for question information though. WiFi should be ok on a regular plane but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 5):

None of the GoPro cameras can geotag photos. Because they don't have GPS built in, or any way of connecting to a separate device. The GoPro app does not support geotagging.

So your aerial photos will not be geotagged. But you can geotag them afterwards. ie use a GPS device to record a tracklog, then sync this with the timestamps of the photos. There is a variety of software to do this, one free option for Windows is GeoSetter. For recording the GPS track, you could use an app on the Ipad, assuming it has a good view of the sky, and can get a good GPS signal.

Note for syncing, it helps if the time is accurately set on the camera. You can use the GoPro app on the Ipad to set the time. Or take a photo of your GPS device, with it showing the time. Then you can calculate the offset from that.